# Saving classes with XmlSerializer in C# with Unity

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project and I need to save a "grid" of cubes to a file, so that it can be loaded back in at a different moment.

I'm trying to use XmlSerializer for this, but the file is always empty, except for:

`<?xml version="1.0"?> <SerializableGrid xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />`

Forgive me for the messy code - I like to make something work and clean it up later. Here it is:

In the GridManager class: this function should create the serializable class to save to the XML file.

```
private static void SaveGridToFile(Grid.Grid grid, string filepath)
        {
            var serGrid = new Grid.Grid.SerializableGrid(grid.gridTiles, grid.gridSize);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Grid.Grid.SerializableGrid));
            
            using(var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, serGrid);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
```

The Grid class, SerializableGrid class, and GridSize class. I'm using the SerializableGrid, because the Grid class contains a dictionary with GameObjects as values, which can't be serialized.

```
public class Grid
    {
        public Dictionary<GridTile, GameObject> gridTiles = new Dictionary<GridTile, GameObject>();
        public GridSize gridSize;

        public Grid(){ }

        public Grid(GridTile[] tiles, GridSize gridSize)
        {
            gridTiles = new Dictionary<GridTile, GameObject>();
            this.gridSize = gridSize;
        }

        

        public class SerializableGrid
        {
            [XmlArray("TilesList"), XmlArrayItem("GridTile")]
            public GridTile[] TilesList { get; }
            [XmlAttribute("GridSize")]
            public GridSize GridSize { get; }

            public SerializableGrid(Dictionary<GridTile, GameObject> gridTilesDict, GridSize gridSize)
            {
                GridSize = gridSize;
                TilesList = new GridTile[gridTilesDict.Count];
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var p in gridTilesDict)
                {
                    TilesList[i] = p.Key;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            public SerializableGrid(){}
        }
    }
    public abstract class GridSize
    {
        public int R;
        public int C;
        public int H;

        public GridSize(int r, int c, int h)
        {
            R = r;
            C = c;
            H = h;
        }
    }
```

And finally, the GridTile & TileCoordinates classes:

```
public class GridTile
    {
        [XmlAttribute("TileCoordinates")]
        public TileCoordinates Coordinates;
        [XmlAttribute("WorldCoordinates")]
        public Vector3 WorldCoordinates;

        public GridTile(TileCoordinates coordinates, Vector3 worldCoordinates)
        {
            Coordinates = coordinates;
            WorldCoordinates = worldCoordinates;
        }

        public GridTile() { }
        
        public class TileCoordinates
        {
            public float x;
            public float y;
            public float z;

            public TileCoordinates (float x, float y, float z)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.z = z;
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong? The saving function *is* called, as a new file is created when I press the button that calls the function.

I've tried giving all variables that aren't primitive a XML attribute, and making all variables public.

Comment: You are not getting any error so there probably no data in grid.gridTiles

Comment: @jdweng Double checked, when logging the gridTiles dictionary before I would save, it finds 125 pairs. Also, the gridsize is set to 5x5x5, which also doesnt show up

Comment: Shot in the dark but have you tried making your types `[Serializable]` ?

Comment: Use properties instead of fields.

Comment: Is the timestamp of the file getting updates when you run the code?  Where is code that calls SaveGridToFile()